# Unable to get custom headers with Axios in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, axios, fastapi, response-headers, octet-stream

I have an backend application running on fastAPI which I already allow CORS:

```
@app.get("/getfile/{obj_name}")
async def get_single(obj_name: str):
    res = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key='medical-appointment/'+obj_name)
    content = res['Body'].read()
    return Response(content=content,
        headers={
            'Content-Disposition': f'attachment;filename={obj_name}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'X-Header-Custom': 'custom',
        })
```

Also I have my reactJs application running which I'm trying to see the logs but my custom logs are not shown only I can see:

[image]

`content-length: '111852', content-type:'application/octet-stream'}`:

```
const handleFile = () => {

    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getfile/<file>')
      .then((response) => {
    const headers = response.headers;
    console.log(headers);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

But I also checked on browser developers tools and I can see my custom headers:
[image]

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers))`?

Comment: It is only getting me:
{"content-length":"111852","content-type":"application/octet-stream"}

Comment: What version of Axios are you using? I tried with 1.4.0 and was able to log and read _all_ the response headers

Comment: "axios": "^1.4.0",

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get headers adding a parameter as mentioned in this doc [here](https://sailokesh.hashnode.dev/enable-and-configure-cors-in-fastapi) in FastAPI to allow `expose_headers=["*"]`